# Laravel 5.3 Eloquent Union Error

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Tengo la siguiente funcion:

```
 public function searchJoin(){
     $first = $this->getModel()   
                ->join('tarea_x_usuario', 'tarea_x_usuario.idTarea', '=', 'tarea.id')
                ->rightJoin('usuario', 'usuario.id', '=', 'tarea_x_usuario.idUsuario')
                ->join('role_x_usuario', 'role_x_usuario.idUsuario', '=', 'usuario.id')
                ->join('role', 'role.id', '=', 'role_x_usuario.idRole')                
                ->get();


        return $this->getModel()
                ->join('tarea_x_usuario', 'tarea_x_usuario.idTarea', '=', 'tarea.id')
                ->rightJoin('usuario', 'usuario.id', '=', 'tarea_x_usuario.idUsuario')
                ->join('role_x_usuario', 'role_x_usuario.idUsuario', '=', 'usuario.id')
                ->join('role', 'role.id', '=', 'role_x_usuario.idRole')
                ->where('role.role','=','ADMINISTRADORR')
                ->union($first)
                ->get();

    }
```

Me tira el siguiente error:

> BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
>   Method getBindings does not exist.

Tambien probe hacer la siguiente consulta:

public function searchJoin() {

```
$first = $this->getModel()
        ->join('tarea_x_usuario', 'tarea_x_usuario.idTarea', '=', 'tarea.id')
        ->rightJoin('usuario', 'usuario.id', '=', 'tarea_x_usuario.idUsuario')
        ->join('role_x_usuario', 'role_x_usuario.idUsuario', '=', 'usuario.id')
        ->join('role', 'role.id', '=', 'role_x_usuario.idRole')
        ->where('role.role', '=', 'ADMINISTRADORR')
        ->get();


$two = $this->getModel()
        ->join('tarea_x_usuario', 'tarea_x_usuario.idTarea', '=', 'tarea.id')
        ->rightJoin('usuario', 'usuario.id', '=', 'tarea_x_usuario.idUsuario')
        ->join('role_x_usuario', 'role_x_usuario.idUsuario', '=', 'usuario.id')
        ->join('role', 'role.id', '=', 'role_x_usuario.idRole')
        ->get();

dd($first->union($two)->get());
```

}

Las dos consultas funcionan, tira error en el union.

La secuencia de errores son:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿asumo que la primera consulta sí funciona?

Comment: Exactamente. La primera trae la consulta y la única diferencia entre las 2 es que una tiene un where y la otra no. Probé agregando un where a la que no tiene pero tira error siempre. Hasta probé hacer una simple consulta de un usuario que me muestre el nombre y sigue el error.

Comment: Me gustaría ver un poco más como se genera el error, ¿puedes copiar todas sus líneas? (las del error).

Comment: Disculpame, no pude conectarme ayer. Ahí puse la secuencia de errores!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que es porque estas aplicando el metodo `get()` al final.
Sobre la doumentación indica que se aplica antes del  `get`, remuevelos y has la prueba

```
$first = DB::table('users')->whereNull('first_name');

$users = DB::table('users')->whereNull('last_name')->union($first)->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#unions